# Specify compiler for MPC (Makefile, Project, and Workspace Creator)

Tags: makefile

We're using [MPC (Makefile, Project, and Workspace Creator)](http://downloads.ociweb.com/MPC/docs/html/MakeProjectCreator.html) in ACE project and would like to specify different compilers (eg, for cross-compiling to different CPU or embedded, etc)

However, the `Makefile` always gets plain `g++` set in the macro file:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#       Macros
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CXX           = g++
```

How can we specify the compiler suite to use within the workspace (mwc), the base project (mpb), or the project file(s) (mpc) themselves?

The command line to run is:

`mwc.pl -type make -include include /src/corba -relative PRJROOT=./ -expand_vars -value_template optimize=$buildOption -value_template obj_dir=obj/ $mwcFile`

Thanks